# Receiving container as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, g++-4.7

I want to iterate a container inside some template function.If container is deque but type it stores is not known then, I tried:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintDeque(deque<T> d)
{
    deque<T>::iterator it; //error here
    for(it=d.begin();it!=d.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

OR if I try this for unknown container:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintDeque(T d)
{
    T::iterator it;   //error here
    for(it=d.begin();it!=d.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Both give compilation errors. How to create an iterator inside the template function so that I can iterate the container?

Comment: try deque<T>::iterator it or just use auto;

Comment: 1. pass deque by reference or const reference. 2. Try `typedef typename T::iterator buffer_iterator; buffer_iterator it;`

Comment: That `<typename T>` was my mistake Corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void PrintDeque(T d)
{
    typename T::iterator it;   //error here
    for(it=d.begin();it!=d.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

You need `typename` before it because the compiler doesn't know you're naming a type, or a static variable. It's called a dependant type.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

As an aside and to comment on the other answers. Some compilers don't need this, and some do. GCC is one of the compilers that do need this clarification.

Comment: Thanks. That works. What about the first code,for ex: if I want to restrict my function to accept only deque as container but with containing any other datatype?

Comment: Got it working thanks. Just put `typename` before `deque<t>::iterator it` and whola!! it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename range>
void PrintEverythingIn(range C)
{
        for (auto e : C)
                cout << e << ' ';
        cout << endl;
}

deque<int> demo { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20 };

int main() { PrintEverythingIn(demo); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintDeque(deque<T> d)
{
    deque<T>::iterator it;
    for(it=d.begin();it!=d.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This code works fine on my windows with vs12.

---

Note:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintDeque(deque<T> d)
{
    deque<typename T>::iterator it; //error here
    for(it=d.begin();it!=d.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

this code, what you've posted is also working fine on my computer.

Comment: This works with VS, and with Comeau, but not with GCC

Comment: Also, you haven't answered the question, you've just pasted his code back to him and said it works.

Comment: Firstly i used what i use generally i.e. deque<T>::iterator it; instead of deque<typename T>::iterator it; That worked. After that tried the posted code. That also worked.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ididn't know that. Any ref would be very helpful